How to handle Cognito Google Identity Provider missing required attribute?
I am facing an architecuture issue in supporting Google Single Sign On via Cognito on AWS.
Our Cognito pool has three required attributes: email, given_name, family_name.
During testing, when one of these attributes is missing (e.g. I have no family_name set on my google account), the sign in returns an error to my callback url: auth/callback/cognito?error_description=attributes+required%3A+%5Bfamily_name%5D&error=invalid_request
I can not find in documentation or the internet a flow to handle this case. Ideally we would like to just prompt the user for the missing attribute. Does anyone know how to handle this or are we just unable to allow users with missing required attributes? It is not possible to update the required attributes, otherwise I would just prompt them for it after signup.
Here is our relevant cloudformation sections:
  UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-***-user-pool
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - Name: given_name
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        - Name: family_name
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        - Name: email
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
    

  GoogleIdentityProvider:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
    Properties:
      AttributeMapping:
        given_name: given_name
        family_name: family_name
        email: email
      ProviderDetails:
        client_id: !Ref GoogleClientId
        client_secret: !Ref GoogleClientSecret
        authorize_scopes: profile email openid
      ProviderName: Google
      ProviderType: Google
      UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool

